# How to fix No ethernet and no WiFi working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn, ethernet

I was performing a DNS Lookup  using a custom .c file i've written (while on a VPN) and suddenly I lost internet connection and I can't even access the WiFi settings.

I've also tried connecting to ethernet and it doesn't work either (i've tested the same cable with a different machine and it works).

When I open the system settings, under the WiFi page i only have the option to turn On/Off airplane mode and says "No WiFi adapter found". I've also got no ethernet connection so i can't run many commands i already found online.

When I perform ifconfig i see 3 devices: enp0s31f6, lo and wlp0s20f3.

I run rfkill list and there are no blocks.

I also run /etc/init.d/network-manager stop and /etc/init.d/network-manager start and nothing changes.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

How can i fix this?

Comment: Have you removed the custom file and done a hardware reboot?

Comment: there is no need to remove the file since I need to manually run it for it to get executed. (it's also part of a school assignment). And yes i've tried rebooting.

Comment: At this point I would suggest blow it away and reinstall the OS.

Comment: i'd do that but i have a lot of work to submit for tonight so i was looking for a more subtle fix

Comment: Look at `ip route` and read `man ip ip-route route`. Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.